# Convert Python code to Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I have the python piece of code which needs to be converted to Robot Framework.

Here is the python code..

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "G:/"}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chromedriver = "C:/Python27/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

Is it possible to make it work in Robot Framework?

I don't have have much knowledge on Robot Framework.

Answer (score 4):

Using [Selenium2Library](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/), a direct translation of that code would look like this:

```
${chromeOptions}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
${prefs}=    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory    G:/
Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
${chromedriver}=    Set Variable    C:/Python27/chromedriver.exe
Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome    executable_path=${chromedriver}    chrome_options=${chromeOptions}
Go To    http://someurl/
[Teardown]    Close All Browsers
```

This code depends on two library imports - Selenium2Library and Collections. It worked after adjusting your paths to my system.

Comment: I'm getting the following error's:Setting variable '${chromeOptions}' failed: Creating a scalar variable with a list value in the Variable table is no longer possible. Create a list variable '@{chromeOptions}' and use it as a scalar variable '${chromeOptions}' instead.

Comment: Setting variable '${prefs}' failed: Creating a scalar variable with a list value in the Variable table is no longer possible. Create a list variable '@{prefs}' and use it as a scalar variable '${prefs}' instead.

Comment: Setting variable 'Call Method' failed: Invalid variable name 'Call Method'.

Comment: Setting variable '${chromedriver}' failed: Creating a scalar variable with a list value in the Variable table is no longer possible. Create a list variable '@{chromedriver}' and use it as a scalar variable '${chromedriver}' instead.

Comment: @louis: you're doing something wrong if you're getting errors about a variable table -- this code should all be part of a keyword or test case (the example shown in the answer is part of a test case, given the presence of `[teardown]`)

Comment: Bryan is correct. The code was meant to be part of the body of a test case or user keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you know Python already, I'd direct you to any number of questions asking about how to implement Python in Robot Framework (that coding is mostly on the Python side). Much of the code could likely be simplified by the `Open Browser` keyword if all you want to do is open a new browser instance to a webpage. To change settings in Chrome, either refer to the questions that explain how to implement your Python code in Robot Framework or use ombre42's suggestions.